# NUll Pointer Exception using getTilte(); Selenium with Java

Tags: selenium

Have two classes one Login and the other which is the TestNG class, I created variable to get the Title of the page but when trying to run the test it is displaying null pointer exception, if I remove the getTitle variable it runs.

```
package main;


import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class Login {


WebDriver driver ;

By userNameTextBox = By.name("email");
By passwordTestBox = By.id("password");
By loginButton = By.id("signInButton");
String titleText = driver.getTitle();




public Login(WebDriver driver) {

    this.driver=driver;
}


public void setUserName() {

    driver.findElement(userNameTextBox).sendKeys("v-tobias.rivera@shutterfly.com");

}
public void setPassword() {

    driver.findElement(passwordTestBox).sendKeys("Indecomm1");

}
public void clickLogin() {

    driver.findElement(loginButton).click();;

}
```

}

```
package test;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
//import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import java.time.Duration;

//import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import main.Login;



public class LoginTest {

WebDriver driver;
Login objLogin;

@BeforeMethod
public void beforeTest() {
    System.setProperty("chromedriver", "/Users/tobiasriveramonge/eclipse- 
workspaceAutomation/seleniumAutomation");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://accounts.shutterfly.com/? 
    redirectUri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.shutterfly.com%2F&cid=&brand=SFLY&theme=SFLY");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(30));
    WebElement element = 
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("email")));
    element.isDisplayed();
}

@Test
public void Test() {
    objLogin = new Login(driver);
    //String title = objLogin.getTitle();
   // System.out.println(title);
    //Assert.assertTrue(loginPageTitle.toLowerCase().contains(" "));
    objLogin.setUserName();
    objLogin.setPassword();
    objLogin.clickLogin();
}

@AfterTest
public void afterTest() {
    driver.quit();
}

}
```

I would like to know why am I getting this exception.

Hi, Have two classes one Login and the other which is the TestNG class, I created variable to get the Title of the page but when trying to run the test it is displaying null pointer exception, if I remove the getTitle variable it runs.

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialize the `driver` object.
That's why referencing to that not initialized object throws the  null pointer exception.
You only declared the `driver` object type by

```java
WebDriver driver;
```

but never initialized it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did something different, I changed the position of this line String titleText = driver.getTitle(); and it worked, it returns now the correct page title. I think that in some point when compiling, that variable was empty. @prophet your recommendation, even though the issue was fixed in different way is to always do Webdriver driver = new ChromeDriver();?

Comment: You have to initialize the `driver` with something like `Webdriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`. This can be done by some alternative ways, but still initialization should be done.